# Unable to compile my first JSP program

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
 <body>


  <form method=post action="Check.jsp">


 <center><h3>Voter Application</h3></center>
 Enter your Age:<input type="text" name="age">
 <input type="submit" value = "Check Age">
 </form> 


 </body>
```

Second jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>


<body>
<% int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParametes(age));
    if(age>=18){
%><h1>You are eligible to vote</h1>
<% else{ %> <h2>Sorry, you cant vote yet</h2>
<%} %>
</body>
</html>



     </html>
```

Here is the error: The second JSP shows a compilation error at the ending curly brace of else. All of the java code is within the <% %> as per the rules but I cant get my around this one. After running the program on the server the error is HTTP status 500 . Unable to compile class for JSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a curly brace on the `else` line. Change to this:

```
<% } else { %> <h2>Sorry, you cant vote yet</h2>
```

Comment: A better way to express your thanks would be to upvote this response and accept it as the answer.

Comment: @BrianShowalter A user with reputation 1 can't upvote.

Comment: yerp, cant do it mate. deserve a accept tho. @BrianShowalter

Answer (score 0):

Never use Scriplet, instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

You can use the [`<c:if>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html) or [`<c:choose>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html)

Change : (correct version) 1. `request.getParameter("age")`  2. `} else {`

```
<% int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
if(age>=18){%>
       <h1>You are eligible to vote</h1>
<%} else { %>
       <h2>Sorry, you cant vote yet</h2>
<%} %>
```

To:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.age>=18 }">
        <h1>You are eligible to vote</h1>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <h1>You are eligible to vote</h1>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

OR

```
<c:if test="${param.age>=18 }">
    <h1>You are eligible to vote</h1>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${param.age<18 }">
    <h1>Sorry, you cant vote yet</h1>
</c:if>
```

---

Read more about [JSP - Implicit Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)

> `param:` Maps a request parameter name to a single value

Comment: thanks for the answer. Guess we havent reached there in class yet. Just learnt scriplets for now. But yeah cheers for the heads up